# Find Probability that difference between two selected numbers do not exceed a particular value

Tags: probability, statistics, combinations

A bag contains $n$ tickets numbered $1$ to $n$. If two tickets are drawn, what is the probability that difference of numbers does not exceed $m$?

The total number of cases is $\dbinom{n}{2}$. But have no clue about the favourable number of cases.

Comment: Sometimes these questions can be approached by picking specific numbers and then seeing how to generalize.  Suppose $n = 100$ and $m = 10$.  And suppose the first ticket is $43$.  Which second tickets would qualify?  What is the probability of drawing such a second ticket?  (Keep in mind that there are only $99$ tickets remaining at that point, so the probability should be of the form $k/99$.)  There are special cases for when the first ticket is $1$ through $10$, or $91$ through $100$; how do you account for those?

Comment: Is $m$ also an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take, for example, $n=8$, $m=3$.

[image]

The red squares are the bad results, the gray are the good ones. (Each number in yellow tells the diffence between the pair values)

There are $(n-m)(n-m-1)/2=10$ bad results, $n(n-1)/2$ is the total number.

Then $$P=1-\frac{(n-m)(n-m-1)}{n(n-1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $m\ge n$ then the probability is equal to $1$. So let $1\le m\le n-1$ and $m$ an integer. Denote with $T_1$ the number of the first ticket and with $T_2$ the number of the second ticket. Then you want to calculate the probability 
\begin{align}P(|T_2-T_1|\le m)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}P\left(|T_2-T_1|\le m \mid T_1=k\right)P(T_1=k)\\[0.3cm]&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(|T_2-k|\le m)\frac{1}{n}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(k-m\le T_2\le m+k)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{j=k-m,\,j\neq k}^{k+m}P(T_2=j)\right)=\dots\end{align}
Now, observe that $k-m$ can be less than $1$ and similarly $k+m>n$. However, whenever $1\le j\neq k\le n$ then $P(T_2=j)=\dfrac{1}{n-1}$. So, $$\sum_{j=k-m, \, j\neq k}^{k+m}P(T_2=j)=\frac{1}{n-1}\cdot\left(\min\{k+m,n\}-\max\{k-m,1\}\right)$$ Since $1\le m \le n-1$ by assumption, this gives 
\begin{align}\dots&=\frac1{n(n-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\min\{k+m,n\}-\max\{k-m,1\}\right)\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}\min\{k+m,n\}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\max\{k-m,1\}\right]\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-m}(k+m)+\sum_{k=n-m+1}^{n}n-\sum_{k=1}^{m}1-\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}(k-m)\right]\\[0.3cm]&=\frac{m(2n-m-1)}{n(n-1)}\end{align}